# Accept all Auto-Correct suggestions?

Tags: ios, nsstring, spelling, misspelling

In my app, I receive a NSString from a server. The thing is, I want to accept ANY Auto-Correct words it recommends. Is this possible with JUST a NSString? Or is there any other way I can go to achieve this feature?

Any tips/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!